# Jump List - UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP app published in Microsoft/Windows Store, and I am working in a new update. I want add a jump list to my app. I already read Docs of Microsoft but I dont understand how make a jump list to my app. I want put in my jump list, XAML pages of my app. The user click in an item of jump list and go to the XAML page. How I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have pages called `SecondPage` and `ThirdPage` that you want to navigate straight from the `JumpList`.

First, you need to add the corresponding items to the `JumpList` itself:

```
JumpList jumpList = await JumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();

jumpList.Items.Clear();
jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToSecondPage", "Go directly to the 2nd page"));
jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToThirdPage", "Visit 3rd page"));

await jumpList.SaveAsync();
```

The standard place to perform this operation is in the `OnLaunched` method of your app (`App.xaml.cs` file). The information about the `JumpListItem` that the user has clicked on is also passed into this method as a parameter, so you may want to place your page navigation logic into the `OnLaunched` method too and make it look like:

```
        if(e.Arguments == "GoToSecondPage")
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
        }
        else if(e.Arguments == "GoToThirdPage")
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ThirdPage));
        }
```

As a result your `App.xaml.cs` file is going to look like this:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    ...
    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ConfigureJumpList();

        ...

        if(e.Arguments == "GoToSecondPage")
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
        }
        else if(e.Arguments == "GoToThirdPage")
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ThirdPage));
        }
    }
    ...
    private async Task ConfigureJumpList()
    {
        JumpList jumpList = await JumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();

        jumpList.Items.Clear();
        jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToSecondPage", "Go directly to the 2nd page"));
        jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToThirdPage", "Visit 3rd page"));

        await jumpList.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

If you use Template 10, then everything is the same, except for some minor code changes and the fact that you edit `OnStartAsync()` instead of `OnLaunched()` method, so the end result in `App.xaml.cs` file should look like:

```
sealed partial class App : Template10.Common.BootStrapper
{
    ...
    public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((args as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).Arguments == "GoToSecondPage")
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.SecondPage));
        else if ((args as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).Arguments == "GoToThirdPage")
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.ThirdPage));
        else
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MainPage));

        await ConfigureJumpList();
    }
    ...
    private async Task ConfigureJumpList()
    {
        JumpList jumpList = await JumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();

        jumpList.Items.Clear();
        jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToSecondPage", "Go directly to the 2nd page"));
        jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToThirdPage", "Visit 3rd page"));

        await jumpList.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

And if you'd like to display a custom icon in a `JumpListItem`, then all you need to do is to replace this line of code

```
jumpList.Items.Add(JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToSecondPage", "Go directly to the 2nd page"));
```

with the following lines

```
var secondPageItem = JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("GoToSecondPage", "Go directly to the 2nd page");
secondPageItem.Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Icons/Page2Icon.png");
jumpList.Items.Add(secondPageItem);
```

where `"ms-appx:///Icons/Page2Icon.png"` is the path to the icon (in this example the *Page2Icon.png* file in the *Icons* folder of the project).

Comment: Thank you very much! But there is a problem. I am using Template10, and give me this error: "App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs)': cannot override inherited member 'BootStrapper.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs)' because it is sealed"